# MongoDB test with chai failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm taking the mongoDB course on how to connect node to MongoDB.
I only wrote this ( in the file they gave for the course) :

```
    let result = await movies.findOne(
      {  countries: { $in: countries} },
      { projection : { title : 1}}
    )

    expect(result).not.toBeNull()
```

and got this error :

```
> server@1.0.0 test /Users/gaetan/WorkSpace/Back et front/Back/mflix-js
> jest --passWithNoTests "projection"

Determining test suites to run...Setup Mongo Connection
(node:5066) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
 FAIL  test/projection.test.js
  Projection
    ✕ Can perform a country search for one country (126ms)
    ✕ Can perform a country search for three countries (65ms)

  ● Projection › Can perform a country search for one country

    Invalid Chai property: toBeNull

      60 |       { projection : { title : 1}}
      61 |     )
    > 62 |     expect(result).not.toBeNull();
         |     ^
      63 |     expect(Object.keys(result).length).toBe(2)
      64 | 
      65 | 

      at Object.proxyGetter [as get] (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/proxify.js:78:17)
      at _callee3$ (src/dao/moviesDAO.js:62:5)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, and I don't understand the log.
Any ideas ?

Comment: could you provide a log of result itself, I'm guessing that this is a problem with jest not your mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the Chai problem is now gone. I just removed the code using it. Never heard of it before, it looks cool. Now to understand the drivers for mongoDB.
The course is pretty fuzzy and unclear IMO.

Thanks a lot anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a discussion in github it is better to use other functions for `not null` check, it is look like there was some changes in their api

```
expect(foo).toBeTruthy();
expect(foo).not.toEqual(null);
```

Comment: sure, https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/5479